# The Apache DolphinScheduler scheduling system is interrupted when scheduling tasks

Tags: apache-dolphinscheduler

The Apache DolphinScheduler scheduling system is interrupted when scheduling tasks. I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this.

```html
[INFO] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.281 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterExecThread:[792] - add task to stand by list: dal_xwj_makeup_activity
[INFO] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.282 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterTaskExecThread:[216] - task ready to submit: TaskInstance{id=5340, name='dal_xwj_makeup_activity', task
Type='SHELL', processDefinitionId=5, processInstanceId=353, processInstanceName='null', taskJson='{"conditionResult":"{\"successNode\":[\"\"],\"failedNode\":[\"\"]}","conditionsTask":false,
"depList":[],"dependence":"{}","forbidden":false,"id":"tasks-29147","maxRetryTimes":1,"name":"dal_xwj_makeup_activity","params":"{\"rawScript\":\"echo \\\"makeup_making_machine running
。。。\\\"\\n/opt/imsxwj/anaconda3/bin/python dal_xiwujie/makeup_making_machine.py\",\"localParams\":[],\"resourceList\":[{\"res\":\"dal_xiwujie/makeup_making_machine.py\",\"name\":\"makeup
_making_machine.py\",\"id\":127}]}","preTasks":"[]","retryInterval":1,"runFlag":"NORMAL","taskInstancePriority":"MEDIUM","taskTimeoutParameter":{"enable":false,"interval":0},"timeout":"{\"e
nable\":false,\"strategy\":\"\"}","type":"SHELL","workerGroup":"default"}', state=SUBMITTED_SUCCESS, submitTime=Wed Oct 20 10:00:00 CST 2021, startTime=null, endTime=null, host='null', exec
utePath='null', logPath='null', retryTimes=0, alertFlag=NO, processInstance=null, processDefine=null, pid=0, appLink='null', flag=YES, dependency='null', duration=null, maxRetryTimes=1, ret
ryInterval=1, taskInstancePriority=MEDIUM, processInstancePriority=MEDIUM, dependentResult='null', workerGroup='hdp', executorId=2, executorName='null'}
[INFO] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.282 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterExecThread:[805] - remove task from stand by list: dal_xwj_makeup_activity
[ERROR] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.282 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterTaskExecThread:[230] - submit task  Exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterBaseTaskExecThread.dispatchTask(MasterBaseTaskExecThread.java:221)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterBaseTaskExecThread.submit(MasterBaseTaskExecThread.java:175)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterTaskExecThread.submitWaitComplete(MasterTaskExecThread.java:92)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterBaseTaskExecThread.call(MasterBaseTaskExecThread.java:272)
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterBaseTaskExecThread.call(MasterBaseTaskExecThread.java:50)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[INFO] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.288 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.service.process.ProcessService:[845] - start submit task : dal_xwj_makeup_activity, instance id:354, state: RUNNING_EXECUTION
[ERROR] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.289 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterTaskExecThread:[231] - task error : %s
[ERROR] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.289 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterTaskExecThread:[183] - task commit  failed , taskId 5340 has already retry 1 times, please check
```

Comment: When there is a problem with the scheduling system built by a single machine, the CPU and memory usage are not high. What is the problem?

Comment: version 1.3.6,The last version also had the same problem, I tried to change a new version 1.3.6 and found the same problem.  In the case that instances are not deleted, this error occurs during scheduling, which is occasional but with a high frequency. This problem will occur almost every day during scheduling execution, but it will not occur occasionally and can be completed normally.  Moreover, the instances of scheduling interrupts are not unified, and problems may not occur in which instances.

Answer (score 1):

which version?
do you delete the process instance?
i check the 221 line:

```
            /**
             *  taskPriority
             */
            TaskPriority taskPriority = buildTaskPriority(processInstance.getProcessInstancePriority().getCode(),
                    processInstance.getId(),
...
```

if you delete the process instance, there would be a NPE.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: ERROR] 2021-10-20 10:00:00.282 org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterTaskExecThread:[230] - submit task  Exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.apache.dolphinscheduler.server.master.runner.MasterBaseTaskExecThread.dispatchTask(MasterBaseTaskExecThread.java:221)
    at ...